# How obtain connect with OAuth 2 using Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, postman

My API uses the [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) ([omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth)) gem for authentication in the Rails 5 backend. The frontend are using [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) (Angular 1.x).

I have all the API requests in Postman. I did the security implementation and I need authenticate Postman with every request. Devise_token_auth uses authentication with OAuth 2 and I am having difficulty to implementing this authentication.

[image]

For this type of authentication, using Postman, what is the process needed to obtain the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the token, there are few things you need to setup.
The client ID, client Secret are the things to be added into your identity serve as clients. 
The Auth Url and access token url will be provided by the identity server and you will be able to get the url by hitting the identity server website when its ready for testing.

The grant type also is dependent upon how you setup the client. For the first time try doing the access token instead of authorization code flow.

For the authorization code flow its a two step process. Get the code first and use the code to get the token.

I recomment watching this tutorial which will help you in understanding Identity server and oauth better.

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/oauth2-openid-connect-angular-aspdotnet/table-of-contents